# SwiftUI Make LazyVGrid Width Fill The screen Inside HStack

Tags: ios, swiftui, hstack, lazyvgrid

I try to have three LazyVGrid inside HStack and each one has the width of the screen, so the middle one will appear and the other two once will became on the left and right of the screen (as shown in the picture below), the problem that it's not fit on all iPhone sizes, if you have any idea hoe to fix this please share it.

The Code

```
@State private var numbers = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
private let columns = Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 41, maximum: .infinity)), count: 7)

var body: some View {
    HStack(spacing: 10) {
        ForEach(numbers, id: \.self) { numberArray in
                LazyVGrid(columns: columns, alignment: .center, spacing: 0, pinnedViews: []) {
                    ForEach(numberArray, id: \.self) { number in
                        Text("\(number)")
                            .background(.blue.opacity(0.3))
                    }
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(.blue.opacity(0.1))
        }
    }
}
```

The view on iPhone 8

[image]

The view on iPhone 13 Pro Max

[image]

Answer (score -1):

**First of all, the same item cannot be found in the array.**

```
 @State private var numbers = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [11, 22, 33, 44,` 55, 66, 77], [12, 23, 34, 45, 56, 67, 78]]
```

**You should write columns like this.**

```
private var columns = [
    GridItem(.flexible()),
    GridItem(.flexible()),
    GridItem(.flexible()),
    
]
```

**You should add scrollview**

```
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
                ForEach(numbers, id: \.self){ arr in
                    ForEach(arr, id: \.self){ item in
                        Text("\(item)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**This is the code I wrote. I hope it was a useful answer.**

```
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {

@State private var numbers = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77], [12, 23, 34, 45, 56, 67, 78]]


private var columns = [
    GridItem(.flexible()),
    GridItem(.flexible()),
    GridItem(.flexible()),
    
]
var body: some View {
    HStack(spacing: 10) {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
                ForEach(numbers, id: \.self){ arr in
                    ForEach(arr, id: \.self){ item in
                        Text("\(item)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not necessary to use the same view structure that I used, you can use any type of SwiftUI views but the important thing for me to have three views each one has The screen width and of the middle one shown on screen and the other two once hidden on the right and left of the screen, but with "Tolga Kağan" its not achieve what I want.

Comment: You're right my code doesn't give that. I can't help with this issue